# Automatically log Skype calls to Outlook calendar

Tags: microsoft-outlook, skype, calendar

I spend a lot of my work day in Skype meetings, these show as meetings in my outlook calendar.

I also receive direct calls through skype and I would like these direct calls to appear in my calendar automatically. Is is possible?

The calendar entry duration should correspond to the call and the subject should be the caller.

I know I can see the call history in Skype but I would also like it in my calendar.

Comment: What do you mean by log? Record audio or save chat? Do you have Skype or Skype for business? Is it important to save to calendar or would saving to a folder could work too?

Comment: Do you want the direct calls to appear in your calendar as a *result* of having had the call, or in advance like other scheduled appointments?

Comment: sounds like a job for a superprogrammer =]